# Select Entire Seam

Tags: edges

I have a mesh with a continuous seam. Is there a way to select all of the continuous edges where the seam is? I tried using the ALT+SHIFT+RMB on the edge, but Blender is unable to select all of the edges at once due to the irregular shape.

[image]

Comment: You could always use select similar (`Shift + G`). That would select all by trait, so would work if it's the only seam.

Comment: I tried using that approach. Blender will select all the seams on the mesh instead of just that seam "island".